# ASP.NET Core EF Performance loss due to migration?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, asp.net-core, migration

I have just migrated my asp.net core web app's database from Sql Server to MySQL. It went very smooth but i am noticing a loss in performance. When i change my database back to the SQL Server, the page loads in less then one second. When im using the MySQL database, it takes +- 15 seconds to load the page. They both have the same data. It is not just on this page; I just picked this one out as an example.

I use Entity Framework and I query for all the Sales in my database (+- 100 records). I use IQueryable and then return it to the View. When I am debugging I can tell the queries go pretty fast, but when I return my View, this is where it starts to slow down.

```
        public IActionResult SalesOverview()
        {
            var sales = _repo.QueryAsNoTracking().
                .Select(result => new
                {
                    Id = result.Id,
                    ClientId= result.Client.Id,
                    ClientNamr = result.Client.Name,
                    DeliveryDate = result.DeliveryDate,
                    NumberOfDetails = result.NumberOfDetails.Count
                });

               return View(sales);
        }
```

Did I miss out on anything during the migration? I'm pretty sure it is not my code because it runs fine with the SQL Server

Kind regards,
Brian

Comment: Indexes for example?

Comment: @nbk thank you for your reply. I have an Index set on my PK column (ID) this came trough the migration (MySQL Workbench)

Comment: if you know the exact query, you can run an EXPLAIN to see, what is happening. In Worst case you will find it in the gnral log which has to be enabled for thso pupose and alo disabled when done

Comment: When i perform the query but return an empty object to the View, the page loads instantly. When I return my Object, it takes +- 15 seconds

Comment: the result gets parsed, but is something that i haven't looked into

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and the schema of the table(s).